# git will not push to remote branch "Everything up-to-date"

Tags: git

I looked at the current solutions on here for the problem I am having but their answers offered doesn't seem to solve the problem of getting the push to work.

I have a local branch called "dev" that is suppose to track a remote branch "v1.0-7.22-dev".

I cloned the repo, and checked out the remote branch "v1.0-7.22-dev" as local "dev".

I made a commit to my local "dev" and when I run git status I get the following:

```
$ git status
# On branch dev
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/v1.0-7.22-dev' by 3 commits.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

When I commit:

```
$ git push
Password: 
Everything up-to-date
```

My config file (**the server name and repo name has been redacted**)

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = ssh://[server-URL]/[remote-repo-directory]
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "dev"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/v1.0-7.22-dev
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
git push origin dev:v1.0-7.22-dev
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a local branch `dev`, which tracks the remote branch `v1.0-7.22-dev` on origin.

If you just say `git push` you do not explicitly specify what to push where and the result depends on the value of `git config push.default`.

If this value is not set, older git versions default to pushing all local branches to a remote branch of the same name. (In your case this would create a branch `dev` on origin, but as you are tracking `v1.0-7.22-dev` you will still be ahead of it.)

You probably want to set push.default to `upstream`. Then a simple `git push` will push to its configured upstream branch. - Exactly the way you expected it.